# Deploying software to multiple ubuntu clients

Tags: ubuntu

As a very small organisation, we currently have 5 ubuntu desktops which I manage independently of one another. They all talk to a single auth server, but are running locally installed images of ubuntu, as opposed to network images.

- What are my options for pushing software to all clients simultaneously?
- If we anticipate further growth, would these solutions scale or would it be better to restructure and start with network images (DisklessClient on ubuntu's help pages)

The focus is, as always, cost effective (preferably open-source software). Availability of paid support is not a requirement.

Comment: Found this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/) or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/). They're both excellent for maintaining many systems, and they'll both scale really well.